# NextAuth and Firebase causing SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, next-auth

I'm new to both Next.js and Firebase. I've been trying to use NextAuth.js to authenticate with Discord for my firebase app. However, I ran into an error.
[image]

I've tried adding "type": "module" into my package.json file and converting all my imports into requires instead but I still get the same error.

This is my firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { getApps, getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

export const app = getApps.length > 0 ? getApp() : firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

This is my [...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../../../lib/firebase";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_SECRET
        }),
    ],
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firebaseConfig),
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I went through this as well. I found using a simple config easier and exporting the default app into your component. Then in the component, add the extra functionality.

Here is my config;

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default app;
```

then in controller...

```
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import app from '../services/firebase';

const rtdb = getDatabase(app);
```